# Exclude PHP files from being displayed together with images

Tags: php

I got a script that displays all my images from folder, but it's displaying a PHP file as well. How can I exclude it?

```
$images_dir = "/Images/";
$images = scandir($images_dir);
arsort($images);
$ignore = array(".", "..", ".php");
foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo "<a href=\"$images_dir$curimg\"><img src=\"". $images_dir . '/' . $curimg ."\" data-src=\"". $images_dir . '/' . $curimg ."\"></a>\n";
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried adding ".php", but it still includes it.

Comment: `in_array` searches for the exact match

Comment: add `$extension = pathinfo($curimg, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` inside your loop to extract the extension from the path

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? This looks like code that can easily be debugged